# text of div in nested divs htmlagilitypack

Tags: .net, winforms, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

i have the div element

```
<div title="View this search: Actives">
<div style="float:right;">
<span class="count" title="some title" id="search_201204">
34 New or Changed
</span>
<span id="trash_2012">&nbsp;&nbsp;X</span>
</div>
The value i need
<div style="padding-left:20px;color:#888"></div>
</div>
```

i need to get the innertext of the outer div with title contains `some title`.

i have this code

```
divs = docNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@title, 'View this search:')]")
If divs Is Nothing Then Continue For
For Each div In divs
    If div Is Nothing Then Continue For
    If ListSearch.Contains(div.InnerText) = False Then
        ListSearch.Add(div.InnerText)
    End If
Next
```

this gives me

> 34 New or Changed   XThe value i need

instead of

> The value i need

which is the text of the outer div.

Please offer any solution you have.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following XPath:

```
//div[contains(@title, 'View this search:')]/child::text()/following-sibling::text()
```

Comment: thanks very much. did you use any tool in constructing this statement, or how did you figure it out?